# When will Spanish be available in Google Actions?

Tags: actions-on-google, api-ai

I have created an actions app in api.ai and if I test it from api.ai directly it can answer to spanish and english intents.

But if I test it in the google actions simulator it only understands english intents.

Is there any way I can make it work in Spanish? is English only available by now? If so... do you know when will be available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, en-US is the only language/country supported in Actions on Google. Google has announced that additional languages, such as en-UK, French, and German, will be available later this year. While "other languages" will also be available later this year, Spanish was not, specifically, mentioned.